# Can't run bundle exec command. Ruby seems unable to find gem even though gem has been installed?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to run a local instance of Github Pages using Jekyll. As far as I understand, the error I'm getting indicates that dependency webrick cannot be located, but it has already been installed.

Main Error Log

[image: Main Error Log]

Webrick Path

[image: Webrick Path]

Gems Environment

[image: Gems Enviroment]

I've tried reinstalling bundler, Ruby, Webrick like other solutions indicate, but I really don't know what to do next now.

Comment: When using Bundler, you are supposed to define dependencies in your `Gemfile`. Try putting webrick in your Gemfile (as `gem 'webrick'`) and run `bundle` afterwards to install it.

Comment: Stefan is right. Ruby 3.0 no longer comes with webrick, run `bundle add webrick` to add webrick to your  Gemfile, see https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/752.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)